# Hide table's tbody when clicked on thead

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table structure as given below.

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

I want to toggle show/hide the tbody and tfoot when clicked on first row of thead. I tried many thing but fail as there could be multiple such table. 
I am using jquery.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show this in fiddle? @Jafar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my work:

```
$(document).on('click','thead',function(){
       $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').toggle();
       $(this).closest('table').find('tfoot').toggle();
    });
```

Heres the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbsZZ/)

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$('thead').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().toggle(); //$(this).siblings('tbody, tfoot').toggle();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sUe7P/)

Comment: Like the use of `siblings` :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('thead tr:first-child').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('tbody, tfoot').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to:

```
$('thead').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('tbody, tfoot').toggle();
});
```

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/E6vPb/1/

Comment: I dont want to hide the whole table. just tbody and tfoot.

Comment: this is hiding the whole page.

Comment: Did you check the JS fiddle? Maybe it it because now all headers react this way. Better is to use a class or id. Do it on `$('#mytable thead').click` or `$('.clicktables thead').click` instead of all the `thead` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You said on the first row of thead,
 so :

```
 $('thead tr').on("click",function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').hide();
   $(this).closest('table').find('tfoot').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all thead's, bind them on click event handler that finds which table you clicked, and toggles (show/hide) tbody and tfoot of this table.

```
$('thead').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    table.children('tbody').toggle();
    table.children('tfoot').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/9Tbv6/

**EDIT**

If you want only first row in thead to be "clickable" change selector in first line of code to:

```
$('thead').children('tr:first-child').click( ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/9Tbv6/2/